# Javascript OOP contructor initializes data with ajax - not available in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I have a problem with implementing a javascript class whose constructor is populated by an ajax call. The data is read from a file and populates correctly the class properties in an asynchroneous manner. The following code works alright:

```
function Pattern(file){

    this.pattern = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: file,
        dataType: 'text',
        context: this,
        success: function (data){
            ...
            this.buildPattern(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Problem loading file \'' + file + '\'');
        }
    });
}

Pattern.prototype.buildPattern = function(pattern){
    do{
        ...
        this.pattern[i][j] = pattern[i][j];
        ...
    }while(pattern[k] != '!');
}
```

The problem happens when I access another method after instancing the class:

```
Pattern.prototype.getPattern = function(number){
    ...
    return this.pattern;
}
```

Using this code:

```
var pattern1 = new Pattern('filename.ext');
var myPattern1 = pattern1.getPattern(1);
```

Due to the asynchronous way of initializing my properties in the class, calling the method getPattern() just after class creation returns an empty result as this.pattern has not yet completed loading and post-processing.

I know there exist jQuery objects Deferred and Promise but I haven't found any implementation of them using javascript and classes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write this as answer and not as comment my tablet wouldn't let me write comments at the moment.

I just thought you might trigger an event (maybe use PubSub) and put the code that uses the class in a EventHandler-function that is triggered after your class is loaded completely.